# multiple plots with r

Tags: r, data-visualization

Any ideas how I can obtain the following plot by using r?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV! Questions solely about programming are off-topic here. Moreover, if you want help reproducing a figure, try showing first what you have done so far. This is not a forum for others to your work.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** I agree that this is off-topic, but will inconvenience
a few electrons for a quick answer.

If the question is how to get several panels in the same figure,
then use `par(mfrow=c(r,c))` to make a figure with `r` rows and `c`
columns. The panels will be arranged row-wise in sequence.
If you want them arranged column-wise, use `mfcol` instead. When
you are done with multi-panel figures, use `par(mfrow=c(1,1))`
to return to the default single-panel figures.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3)); set.seed(1030)
x = rnorm(25);  hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2");  lines(density(x), col="red")
y = rnorm(250);  hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2");  lines(density(y), col="red")
z = rnorm(2500);  hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2");  lines(density(z), col="red")
    curve(dnorm(x), add=T, col="darkgreen", lwd=2, lty="dashed")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]